# Sort tow file using comm and sort function

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I want to compare with online users inside  freeradius database and users inside mikrotik devices , so I retrieved online users from freeradius and insert them inside file1, get online users from mikrotik and insert them inside file2, now I want to get the users that are found in file2 but not found inside file1 
so I used this code

I am trying to get users that are found in file2 but not found in file 1.

```
 comm -23 <(sort < file2) <(sort  file1)
```

but I had this error

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected.
```

So where is my error?

actually I don't know much things about bash and shell , so please help me

Comment: Seems like you have a `<` too much for file2

Comment: What shell are you using? Not all common ones support the `<(command)` syntax - including dash, which is used for Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Your immediate problem is probably that you used `sh` to execute a Bash script. See the second duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files contain 1 username per line in file1, a simple one liner like the below should do what you need, without having to sort the files :

```
while read line; do if grep -q "$line" file2; then echo "user in both :" "$line"; fi; done < file1
```

Comment: @tripleee fixed

Comment: That's also going to be far more inefficient if the files are of any significant size.

Comment: @Shawn, ok but are you sure that sorting 2 big files instead before comparing them would be more efficient ?

Comment: Two `O(N log N)` sorts and one `O(N)` comparison of the results vs basically an `O(N^2)` loop? Wouldn't be surprised, no.

Comment: It's not an `O(N^2)` loop scan. Only 1 file is scanned, once : _I am trying to get users that are found in file2 but not found in file 1_

Comment: For every line in file1 you look at up to every line in file2. It's a nested loop.

Comment: There's also a potential problem if any line in file1 has regexp metacharacters, but that's trivial to fix.

Comment: @funkyjelly, ...short answer is that GNU sort is aggressively optimized; f/e, if you have inputs too large to fit in memory, it sorts subsets of the file into different temporary files per each, and does a merge-sort to combine them together. If you have inputs big enough to need that kind of optimization, running grep once per line is almost unthinkably inefficient in comparison (and the `awk`-based alternatives are going to run one out of memory quickly).

Comment: @Charles thanks for the info. I was not aware of this sort optimization you just explained.